# How can I use langmap and noremap together?

Tags: key-bindings

I set the following on my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set langmap=qd,QD
```

However, `q` does not work since I set the following (so `q` just moves the cursor to left):

```
noremap d h
noremap h gj
noremap t gk
noremap n l
```

So I set them to `langmap` as well:

```
set langmap=qd,QD,dh,hj,tk,nl,ln,LN
```

However, when I type in `h`, it inserts a line, since I also set the following:

```
nnoremap j o<Esc>k
```

To recap, I want to set the `q` to `d`, which then makes `noremap d h` not working, so I added it to `langmap` as well, but it then becomes incompatible with other remap settings.

So is it possible to set the `langmap` as well as `noremap`, without the keys being set recursively?

I use Dvorak so I want to set it like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my answer to your original question on this topic AND in an associated comment to you (!!), the help for `'langmap'` has advice for handling interference from `:map` mappings. Specifically, it suggests resetting of `'langremap'`. When that is off...

> ...setting 'langmap' does not apply to characters resulting from a
>   mapping. This basically means, if you noticed that setting 'langmap'
>   disables some of your mappings, try resetting this option.  This
>   option defaults to on for backwards compatibility.  Set it off if that
>   works for you to avoid mappings to break.

I applied your settings and reset `'langremap'` and `h` no longer inserts a line.

Note, though, that this isn't a panacea for all potential conflicts. If you have a jumble of mappings containing the same keys there may be other problems. You'll need to be judicious in what you decide to map. (And, of course, always use `:noremap` and friends instead of `:map`.)

Comment: Sorry, I thought a mod deleted all of our comments and so I took it to mean I should open a new question. But I later found out that it is a bug happening right now on Safari, that all the comments over SE are not shown.